# Selecting correct ArcGisFeatureLayer to query onSingleTap event?

Tags: android, gis, layer, arcgis

My problem: I'm working on a Android (ArcGis) Attribute Editor following the sample code from their tutorials. The problem occurs when I have more than 1 ArcGisDynamicLayer and, more important, more than 1 ArcGisFeatureLayer.

My question: What is the (correct) approach to IDENTIFY the right Feature Layer to query when I tap on a "field" displayed on the map?

I read a similar question (Arcgis SDK for Android - Query multiple feature layers), but I didn't understand how to use IdentifyTask using only a single tap.

EDIT: I tried to get the graphics that I tapped on to compare it to the graphics from every feature layer. If they are equal, that's the feature layer that I'm looking for. But that's not working, because my feature layers don't seem to have any graphics.

```
mapView.setOnSingleTapListener(new OnSingleTapListener() {

    public void onSingleTap(float x, float y) {

    /*...construct query...*/

    Graphic g = null;
    for (Layer layer : mapView.getLayers()) {
                        if (layer instanceof ArcGISFeatureLayer) {
                            ArcGISFeatureLayer fLayer = (ArcGISFeatureLayer) layer;
                            // Get the Graphic at location x,y
                            final int[] ids = fLayer.getGraphicIDs(x, y, 10, 1);
                            if (ids != null && ids.length != 0) {

                                g = fLayer.getGraphic(ids[0]);
                                System.out.println("Graphic: " + g);
                            }


                    }

    /*...loop through every FeatureLayer and verify like :...*/
    for(...)
        if(layer.getGraphic(g.getUid()) != null && && g.equals(layer.getGraphic(g.getUid()))) {

            /* call the select features method and implement the callbacklistener */
            /* rest of the story */

        }
}
```

Comment: Welcome on stackoverflow, please add at least what you tried until now

Comment: Thank you. I post an edit to my question.